# Maven uppdate version of module and dependencies in modules that use it

Tags: maven, build, dependencies

I'm struggling with updating version of module. 
My project is huge (around 50 modules) but I will simplify it for an example purpouse.

```
-moduleA
  -moduleA1
    -pom.xml
  -pom.xml
-moduleB
  -moduleB1
    -pom.xml
  -pom.xml
-pom.xml
```

What I want to do.
Lets's assume one version in every pom.xml - 5.0.0.
ModuleA1 pomx looks like:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.sample.project</groupId>
    <artifactId>moduleA</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.0</version>
</parent>
<groupId>com.sample.project.moduleA</groupId>
<artifactId>moduleA1</artifactId>
<version>5.0.0</version>
```

Now I want to increase version of moduleA1.
So...

```
mvn -N versions:set -DnewVersion=5.0.1 -DgroupId=com.sample.project.moduleA -DartifactId=moduleA1
```

ModuleB1 has dependency to moduleA1

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.sample.project</groupId>
    <artifactId>moduleB1</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.0</version>
</parent>
<groupId>com.sample.project</groupId>
<artifactId>moduleB1</artifactId>
<version>5.0.0</version>
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.sample.project.moduleA</groupId>
        <artifactId>moduleA1</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Version of this dependency should be updated and it is but only for the first time *when version is the same as parent). If I want to update it to 5.0.2 this dependency will not be changed it will stay 5.0.1 (only pointed moduleA1 will be updated to 5.0.2)
I tried to use dependencyManegement but the result was exactly the same.
Any ideas how to force maven to update pointed module and dependencies of its module on other modules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution.
The key is to set oldVersion parameter to the previous version. Otherwise version:set will use ${project.version} and that's way updating version work for the first time because module version is the same as project.version.

Answer (score 0):

Use `${project.version}` in all module dependencies and you have consistent and up to date versions.

Comment: I don't want to use project.version I need specific version of module. If whole project is 5.0.4 and moduleA1 is 5.0.20 I want to use 5.0.20 as dependency on moduleB1

Comment: You can manage the module versions in properties in the parent poms. Then you need to only set them once.