# maven read version from file with properties-maven-plugin

Tags: maven, plugins, lifecycle

I want to use properties from file and to do so I use properties-maven-plugin. Unfortunately I encounter a problem.

```
dependencies.dependency.version for xxx.jar:jar must be a valid 
version but is '${my-version}'.
```

In versions.properties I defined versions like this:

```
my-version=5.10.15
```

I know that I can put it in  and it works fine but I want to place it in file due to some reasons.

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
            <files>
                <file>versions.properties</file>
            </files>
            </configuration>
    </execution>
</executions>
```

I'm also aware of lifecycles and I know that it will not work if mvn clean will be called but I dont know why it doesnt work when mvn install is called.

Comment: The question is what kind of advantage do you think you get to externalize versions into a property file? What kind of problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: I must agree with @khmarbaise ... The only reason I can see for this, is to read the version from an external source. But guess what, if you need so, you can do it reading the internal *pom.properties* file generated by maven when your application is built.

Comment: My problem was described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54945083/maven-uppdate-version-of-module-and-dependencies-in-modules-that-use-it I have almost 50 modules and it will be much more clear if put in external .properties file than in pom.xml.

Comment: What would you like to put in external files? The dependency versions? You are doing it wrong cause for things like that a dependencyManagement exists etc. I'm working on builds with 1200+ modules. and simply no cause the whole build informations is in the pom file no supplemental source only a single source of truth...

Answer (score 0):

For those, who still struggle with this - I have already answered [almost the same question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75800209/how-can-i-dynamically-add-version-of-any-dependency-in-pom-xml-without-profiling/76317839#76317839). Please, check it out.

Long story short - `maven-properties-plugin` (by the way, please, use [more modern one](https://github.com/Mikhail2048/properties-maven-plugin), if you will need it) will not be able to help you. You need to specify properties via command line for maven to beware about this properties before build. For more detailed answer check my first link