# how can I dynamically add version of any dependency in pom.xml without profiling

Tags: java

I want to dynamically add the version of the dependency using `${variable_name}`, I added that variable in another pom.properties file parallel to the pom. I am getting the "not able to resolve dependencies" error. I am using `properties-maven-plugin`.

I expected that if I used this plugin the plugin would read me the variable that i have defined in pom.properties and I will be able to use that variable in version tag in dependency.
I have used `org.jacoco.jacoco-maven-plugin` to find the solution of this problem.

I have added my `pom.xml` below.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.9</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>project</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>project</name>
    <description>Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>set-property</goal>
                        </goals>
                       
                        <configuration>
                            <files>
                                
                                <file>C:\Users\praduman.yadav\eclipse\learning-workspace\springboot project\project\example-library.properties</file>
                            </files>
                         
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
    
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${example-library.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

I have added the below version variable in my pom.properties below

```
version=0.8.8
```

Comment: Did you have a look at the plugin's [usage page](http://www.mojohaus.org/properties-maven-plugin/usage.html) and try one of the first 2 options which include `<phase>initialize</phase>` and `<goal>read-project-properties</goal>`?

Comment: Why is the `jacoco-maven-plugin` even a dependency, isn't that weird? Also you defined a property named `version` and reference `example-library.version` as a property, that doesn't match.

Answer (score 1):

There a a couple of things to point out

1. If you intend to use maven properties plugin (either a new or an old one, see below), this will not help you. Becuase when maven parses the POM it needs to know the versions already, **it happens before any build**. So by the time of build you should already know the versions of dependencies, not by the time of some build phase. So the plugin you are trying to use is not going to solve this problem.
2. To solve your problem, you can try to pass properties into maven form command line, like `-Dsome.version=1.6.3` for instance. This way, you will provide the property value at the parsing time so the maven will be able to recognize and substitute the variable.

As a side note, talking about `properties-maven-plugin`, there are 2 options, as far as I can tell...

- There is maven properties plugin: https://github.com/mojohaus/properties-maven-plugin. I do not think a lot of people use it since this plugin is no more under active development.
- Or you can use this plugin: https://github.com/Mikhail2048/properties-maven-plugin/tree/v1.0.0. This plugin is a fork of maven plugin but is under active development and is more feature reach.

I only can tell about the later since I myself is one of the contributors to the project - there is a `README.md` file that shows multiple examples of how you can use the plugin. There is an example specifically for your case as well. So check this out.